# Are sources of Jetty public?

Tags: java, jetty

I got the following stacktrace

```
 [15/12/11 05:52:01:001 EET]  WARN EXCEPTION @7361b0bc=POST//xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/service/receiveMessage?nodeType=server&messageType=generatePoster&callerId=null&messageId=21c1f0e4-8ffe-4c4e-ade0-2b475c029203#WAITING(31811ms)->EXCEPTED(1ms)sent=31813ms
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpGenerator.prepareBuffers(HttpGenerator.java:1045)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpGenerator.flushBuffer(HttpGenerator.java:921)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:86)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:609)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:45)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:598)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:533)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
```

(Unfortunately it is the whole stacktrace, which does not refer any of my classes).

It happens a some seconds after I call

```
client.send(exchange);
```

where

```
client = new org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpClient(...)
exchange = new org.eclipse.jetty.client.ContentExchange(...)
```

The version of Jetty jars is 8.1.0.RC0.

My question is : Are the Jetty sources public, and where I can view the sources of HttpGenerator.java?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All of the jetty sources can be found online.

Jetty 6 can be found at codehaus.org

- http://git.codehaus.org/gitweb.cgi?p=jetty-project.git

Jetty 7:

- http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/log/?h=jetty-7
- https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/tree/jetty-7

Jetty 8:

- http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/log/?h=jetty-8
- https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/tree/jetty-8

Jetty 9:

- http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/
- https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project

Note: The jetty project is not allowed to access github pull requests due to Eclipse Foundation policy.

Answer (score 2):

There are sources.jars available at http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/
Yours should be there somewhere, probably jetty-http...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Jetty's source is public (it's a free, open-source project). The code for the specific class you want, `HttpGenerator`, can be viewed at Jarvana and presumably other websites if you don't want to download it; just choose the version you want from [this page](http://jarvana.com/jarvana/search?search_type=class&java_class=org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpGenerator).